# How To Compare Two Sounds In C#....?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm making a desktop dictionary which gives meaning with audio pronouncation and also user could record his pronouncation in .wav format..... and the application would tell him how prefect he is in his pronouncation.......!
**I want to known whether there is way that could help me in comparing the audio file in .wav format....?**
**Not the size actually but the pronouncation.....**
I'm using visual studio 2008